# Tom Dieck's Algebraic Topologie vs Topologie

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology

I have noticed that there is an English and a German book about (algebraic) topology written by tom Dieck:

Algebraic Topology: https://www.ems-ph.org/books/book.php?proj_nr=86

Topologie: https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110802542/html

I have already used the English book, but I do not have a copy of the German one. Do you know how they compare? Does the German book discuss additional topics, and vice versa?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you can understand German, then have a look at the Contents in the Amazon-preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The German book discusses the following topics:

Frontmatter -- I Fundamentalgruppe und Überlagerungen -- II Flächen -- III Homotopiegruppen -- IV Axiomatische Homologie und Kohomologie -- V Singuläre Homologie und Kohomologie -- VI Homotopie -- VII Komplexe -- VIII Mannigfaltigkeiten -- IX Bündel -- X Dualität. Produkte -- XI Charakteristische Klassen -- Literatur -- Index

Here are the English words for it:

Frontmatter -- I Fundamental group and covering spaces -- II Surfaces -- III Homotopy groups -- IV Axiomatic homology and cohomology -- V Singular homology and cohomology -- VI Homotopy -- VII Complexes -- VIII Manifolds -- IX Bundles -- X Duality, products -- XI Characteristic classes -- Literature -- Index